# Display a Joomla layout without page reload

Tags: jquery, joomla

I have lots of tabs in my dashboard. For each tab i put a seperate layout. when the user selects a tab the page gets reloaded.

But now I want to display the page without reload. I used lot of ajax functions inside the  each layout. When i use the load method to load the page it's not working in IE and the datepicker and UI selectable inside the page are not working. Is there any possible to load a layout of the page without reloading.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this excellent plugin to ajaxify your website: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/site-performance/13293

Comment: i want to add this ajax functionality to the layouts in the components that has separate views

Comment: you can't just install a plugin and all your components magically work with ajax. The majority of components are built without ajax thus they refresh on submit etc. A LOT of work has to go into to making a component Ajax based